# Processor compatibility and motherboards

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have a [Intel DG965WH](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/dsktpboards/dg965wh) motherboard. I am looking to upgrade my processor. I've checked the "[Supported Processor](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dg965wh/sb/CS-026598.htm)" list, and I've checked the [compatibility tool](http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?Boardname=dg965wh). I'm still a bit confused because the clock speed of the E6700 processors [being sold online](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116370) do not match the ones listed in the compatibility tool.

Are these newer versions of the E6700 compatible? What are the important factors?

**Update:** This upgrade went off without a hitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is compatible.

When choosing CPU, you need to look at only two things - socket and FSB (bus frequency).

Your motherboard specification says:

> Support for the following:
>
> Intel® Core™2 Duo processor in an
> **LGA775** socket with a **1066** or 800 MHz
> system bus

Which clearly states that this CPU is supported, since it is:

> Core 2 Duo E6700 – 2.67 GHz (4 MB L2, **1066** MHz FSB), **LGA775**

Comment: Sweet thanks - it may seem obvious given the specification, but I wanted a second opinion that these were the key factors.

Comment: It's always good to check twice if you are going to buy something :)