# Can I install a Celeron E3400 in an Intel DG965WH motherboard?

Tags: intel-celeron

Can I install a Celeron E3400 in an Intel DG965WH motherboard?

According to Intel, [E3400 is not in the list of supported CPUs](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dg965wh/sb/CS-026598.htm), but based on [another super user suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/256320/processor-compatibility-and-motherboards) it should qualify, since both the socket type (LGA775) and the FSB frequency (800MHz) are OK.

Has any fellow superuser done this or heard about it being done successfully?

P.S. I want to replace the PentiumD 2.8GHz with the E3400, to get a CPU with VTX (necessary for my work).

Comment: http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?ProcNbr=e3400&BoardName=DG965WH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not in the list, then it's probably not supported.  Of course, you could always try, but be careful because you might be risking permanent damage to the equipment (I wouldn't try it).

In this list of supported processors...  http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dg965wh/sb/CS-026598.htm

...there appears to be a "Processor number" column.  Perhaps this is not the same as the E3400 model number?  Please take a look at your processor to see if one of those numbers in that column is documented on it to help determine if the risk of damage might be lower.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [taspeotis comment above](http://processormatch.intel.com/CompDB/SearchResult.aspx?ProcNbr=e3400&BoardName=DG965WH) - Intel seems to clearly say that I endanger the HW by doing this. Oh well. **UPDATE**: I bought a matching mobo.